# SDL 2 collision detetection

Tags: c++, collision-detection, sdl-2

I am creating a physics simulator of sorts and I have thousands of point-like objects (single pixels) moving at the same time.  The way I have this setup currently is each point moving only one pixel per frame, which makes it easy to keep track of them in a two dimensional array and check if they're going to collide. However, this solution doesn't permit frame independent movement, which is necessary, because the collision detection is very slow. What is the most efficient way of doing collision detection in this case?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "frame independent movement?"

Comment: The frame rate can get quite low if thousands of particles are moving at the same time, which means that they all slow down. What should happen is frames start getting skipped, meaning a point moves more than one pixel in a certain frame, depending on how much lower the current frame rate is than the intended frame rate. This would keep them moving at the same speed despite the lower frame rate.

Comment: Okay, so you mean "frame RATE dependent." Answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, first things first:

On any modern OS, your app will be either

1. Sharing processor time with another app, or the OS itself, which is about the same thing
2. Doing different amounts of work at different times - like, loading assets in the background, rebuilding collision trees, or playing Pac-Man
3. Fighting the flying toasters

Also, you never know what kind of hardware your app, if distributed, will be running on. This entails lots of headaches, but the first and foremost is that you **never** know, at compile time, how much real time has elapsed between frames.

(A funny situation recently arose when a customer wanted an orbital calculation to be correct after he had closed his laptop, got on a plane, and reopened it. Easy enough to fix, but you might want to anticipate a 12 hour per frame situation.)

So, how do you deal with this?

Any framework will provide a timer of some sort. I'm not sure how SDL handles this, but typically, on Windows, you'd use `GetTickCount()` to get the elapsed milliseconds between frames. Each particle has a velocity, expressed in units per second. (Please use meters. Save the world the pain of Units Of user1868866).

When moving the particle,

pos += velocity * elapsed_time;

Or, as a concrete example, if I am in a car moving at 50 mph,

position += 50 miles/hr * 2 hr = 100 miles.

Doing this will solve the problem where particles are moving in frame time instead of simulation/game/real time.

Now, the collision-detection problem. Since we're working in 2D here...

With more than a handful of objects, you can't compare every object to every other object in a reasonable amount of time to see if they collide.

So, we have fancy things like [Quadtrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree). The idea is to partition your space recursively into quadrants, each of which is really a data structure that somehow "contains" all of the items that fall within its bounds. Then, you only have to check for collision between items within the same quadtree node.

Implementation of a quadtree for your specific applicatino is way, way too long to be appropriate for an SO answer, but I encourage you to research it, try and implement it, and come back here with any issues you have. Another great resource is [gamedev.stackexchange.com](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com), which is more game/graphics focused than SO.

Good luck.